# Excel statusbar not updating

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel workbook with 2 sheets. If I view sheet-2 and run a macro (in a module) to update sheet-2, the statusbar correctly updates. The code is:

```
Application.StatusBar = True
Application.StatusBar = Format(rowsdown / 350, "0%") & "   Processing epic: " & epic
```

However, if I view sheet-1 and run the same macro to update sheet-2, the macro runs correctly and updates sheet-2 but the statusbar is not updated.

How can I get the statusbar to update while viewing sheet-1?

Comment: Obviously these lines belong to some Sub, Where does this Sub live? The variables rowsdown and epic declared and where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a public Sub call from within any sheet with appropriate parameters.

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub UpdateStatusBar(rowsdown As Long, epic As Variant)
   Application.StatusBar = True
   Application.StatusBar = Format(rowsdown / 350, "0%") & "   Processing epic: " & epic
End Sub


Sub fromSheet1()
   Call UpdateStatusBar(a, b)
End Sub
```

Copy the public Sub in a module for common use.

Comment: Many thanks to ΑΓΡΙΑ ΠΕΣΤΡΟΦΑ for such a detailed reply. That solution worked perfectly.